# A combinatorial identity with Pochhammer's symbol

Tags: combinatorics, analysis, discrete-mathematics, hypergeometric-function

Let $m,k$ be an positive integers with $k\le m$. I am trying to prove $$\sum_{j=0}^k{\frac{1}{2}\choose k-j}\frac{2^{2j}(m+j)!}{(m-j)!(2j)!}=\frac{P(n,k)}{(2k)!}$$
where $n=2m+1$ and $P(n,k)=\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} (n^2-(2i)^2)$. We can use Pochhammer's symbol and write the left side as
$$(-1)^k\sum_{j=0}^k\frac{(-1/2)_{k-j}(m+1)_j(-m)_j}{(1/2)_j(k-j)!j!}$$
We can also write the right hand side as $$(-1)^k\frac{(-m-\frac{1}{2})_k(m+\frac{1}{2})_k}{(\frac{1}{2})_kk!}.$$ So I think the identity must follow from some identities in hypergeometric functions.  Does anyone see a way to do it?

Comment: Note: Recently duplicated [on MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/129792) and treated there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Treating both sides as coefficients of $x^k$ in a power series with variable $x$, the left-hand side turns into a power-series product, one factor representing $\sqrt{1-x}$. We end up with a special case of the known hypergeometric identity
$$(1-x)^{a+b-c} {}_2F_1(a,b;c;x) = {}_2F_1(c-a,c-b;c;x)$$
with $a = m+1$, $b = -m$, $c = 1/2$.
Cf. (34) of [this MathWorld entry](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html).

Comment: This formula can be found in: Abramowitz, M. and Stegun, I. A. (Eds.). "Hypergeometric Functions." Ch. 15 inHandbook of Mathematical Functions with Formulas, Graphs, and Mathematical Tables, 9th printing. New York: Dover, pp. 555-566, 1972. The formula is 15.3.3 on page 559.